# Как перезагрузить сервер pythonanywhere | How reload pythonanywhere server

Tags: python-3.x, pythonanywhere

Как перезагрузить сервер pythonanywhere?

Answer (score 1):

```
username = 'UserName'
token = 'token'
domain_name = 'UserName.pythonanywhere.com'

response = requests.post(
    'https://www.pythonanywhere.com/api/v0/user/{username}/webapps/{domain_name}/reload/'.format(
        username=username,
        domain_name=domain_name
    ),
    headers={'Authorization': 'Token {token}'.format(token=token)}
)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]